# Troubleshoot Ignite Thread waiting Issue

Tags: multithreading, ignite

```
Thread=[name=sys-stripe-18-#19%xyz-core-server%, id=56], state=WAITING
Locked pages = []
Locked pages log: name=sys-stripe-18-#19%xyz-core-server% time=(1666937416364, 2022-10-28 14:10:16.364)
-> Try Write lock nextOpPageId=844420635195025, nextOpStructureId=default-p-818##CacheData [pageIdHex=0002ffff00007691, partId=65535, pageIdx=30353, flags=00000002]
```

The waiting time seems to be too much, how can we troubleshoot for what it is waiting?

These are Ignite logs.

Tried: Analize logs.
Expecting: Ways to trouble shoot problem that is making my application irresponsive probaby due to this waiting thread.

Comment: Why do you think the waiting time is too much? What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: The application is getting unresponsive, It uses embedded ignite. Can see the above threads waiting for 1666937416364 times apart from that also see "Tomcat log: org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.error Blocked system-critical thread has been detected", Can the above be a reason for unresponsiveness? Thanks!

Comment: Blocked threads are typically the symptom rather than the cause. Chances are you're seeing "Long JVM pauses" on some nodes and are using native persistence?

Comment: yes, what this is an observed behaviour, what can we do to avoid it ?

Comment: You've not given us much to work with. The most common cause is Java garbage collection.

Comment: how can we increase the timeout of the embedded Ignite so that it doesn’t disconnect as we see long JVM pauses

Comment: That would be solving the wrong problem. You should tune the JVM so you don't get JVM pauses.